# display image received from api

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, api-design

I am designing a function that displays an image from an API. The API returns a plain `image/jpeg`. I can change the API to just return the string of the image if needed. How can I display this image as an `<img>` or `<canvas`?

```
  function getPhoto() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value
    var base_url = encodeURI(document.getElementById('base_url').value)
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://api.reteps.tk/getPowerschoolPhoto", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send(`base_url=https://${base_url}&username=${username}&password=${password}`);
    console.log("Image:"+xhttp.IMAGE); // show the image???
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image src attribute like this:

```
$('#myImg').attr('src', RESULT_OF_YOUR_API_CALL);
```

Check out this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1hu6e6a3/